# Searching for a digit and delete it in my int variable

Tags: java, variables, int, digit

I want to search a digit in my int variable and delete it.

Here is little part of the code (not finished, because i'm still on the implementation). I noticed that there are many use cases. So do you know an easier way to delete the digit?

```
public int getStringtoIntForEthType(int OxAB){
        String myInt = Integer.toString(OxAB);
        if(Integer.toString(OxAB).contains("x")){
            myInt = myInt.substring(2);
        }
        StringBuilder myIntBuilder = new StringBuilder(myInt);

        for(int a = 0; a<=myInt.length();a++){
            if(a-1 < 0 && myIntBuilder.charAt(0)!=0 && myIntBuilder.charAt(a)==0){

            }
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(myIntBuilder.toString());
    }
```

Comment: When would Integer.toString contain an "x"? Decimal numbers do not contain "x"

Comment: int 0xAb can only store numbers it will never contain characters, it would throw out NumberFormatException, also in java variable names cannot start with a number

Comment: thats not true. for e.g. 0x800 would give you the int 2048.

Comment: But you are right. 0xAB should be a string

Comment: @Cem Yes, it would, but Java will store the int as `2048`, so Integer.toString will return `"2048"`. You need to change the radix

Comment: what is  "radix"? :D

Comment: Read the JavaDoc for [Integer.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)). You need to set the radix to 16, to make an int to a hexadecimal string

Comment: Ah ok thats good. So i'm using jnetpcap and this api is handling an integer 0x800 like the number 8. So i have to substring the first two and have to search the number.

Comment: For e.g.

0x720 = should be the integer 72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all existence of that Digit from the number here is a function :-

```
public int DeleteDigit(int number, int numberToDel)
{
    String Num = "" + number;
    Num = Num.replace(numberToDel + "", "");

    if(Num.length != 0)
        return Integer.parseInt(Num);
    return 0;
}
```

this would return an integer without the digit

Comment: If you have removed all digits from the number and try to parse it back to an int, there will be an exception right?

Comment: You are right @OrlandoL, didnt think of that.. thanks will update

Comment: Just check if (num.length != 0)

Comment: Yeah you could do that way too @Cem :)

Comment: One question. you aren't using brackets like { for if etc.
I know that is working but why ?

Comment: @Cem you do not require { for single line codes inside if statement, not just if statement even in loops etc you could do the same thing, in fact you could place an ifstatement under a forloop without brackets for example :-for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) if(i  == 100) System.out.println("smthn"); , those are coding styles which vary if interested here is a wider discussion on that https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no